# Is there a way to use VLOOKUP in excel to count certain values in a table, but only for a certain range of the VLOOKUP index?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, countif

I have a large Excel file with dates as one of the variables. I am trying to sum a count of strings from one of the other variables, but only from a certain date range (i.e. count of "Yes" in column C for the most recent 10 days in column A). The date I need to start from is displayed on the main sheet (also where I need to display the count), with the data with the dates being on another sheet. Say whole table ranges from June 1-July 1 in column A, and column C is "yes" or "no".

I'm looking to VLOOKUP the date from the mainsheet to find where it begins in the dates sheet, and count the number of "yes" associated with that start date up until the current date.

I've tried using the INDEX function, making the array parameter begin from the date using VLOOKUP and end with the cell at the last date of the yes/no column (to incorporate all values needed from the date range), with no success.

`=index(vlookup(B1,dates!A:A,1,false):D1000,5,countif(E:E,"Yes"))`

I am getting a #REF! error, stating that the parameter 2 value should be between 0 and 1. I've only tried different variations of this function and VLOOKUP, and can't seem to get around getting an error.

The expected output should be the count of "yes" in column D from the start date specified to the current date in column A.

EDIT: 
[image: Here's a sample image of what I'm looking to do.][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBM8X.png)

2nd Edit:
The dates are pulled from a website and are not formatted as dates, but rather abnormal strings:
Apr 27, 20194/27
Apr 28, 20194/28
Apr 30, 20194/30
May 1, 20195/1
May 2, 20195/2
May 3, 20195/3

Answer (score 1):

Use COUNTIFS:

```
=COUNTIFS(E:E,"Yes",A:A,">="&B1,A:A,"<="&Today())
```

The Above works if your dates are true dates, if Strings Use:

```
=COUNTIFS(INDEX(E:E,MATCH(B1:A:A,0)):E1040000,"Yes")
```

Comment: This worked on my sample data I added a picture of, thank you. However (something I forgot to add), my dates are pulled from a website and are stored as string values that are formatted weird. It didn't work on this data (assuming because the ">=" can't recognize the value of the date?). Here's what the dates look like.
Apr 24, 20194/24  
Apr 26, 20194/26 
Apr 27, 20194/27  
Apr 28, 20194/28  
Apr 30, 20194/30  
May 1, 20195/1  
May 2, 20195/2   
May 3, 20195/3   
May 4, 20195/4   
May 5, 20195/5

Comment: @rm1512 do you always want the last 10?

Comment: No, a series of different ranges (last 10, last 20, last 50, etc...).

Comment: @rm1512 I am still trying to understand what you want.  You want to specify a value and count all "Yes"es from that value to the end of the list?

Comment: Correct. Your first comment worked on the sample data that I put in a picture of. But in the actual data, the dates are formatted as strings that cannot be converted to dates, which is why I think the ">=" did not work because it cannot read it as a numerical or dated value.

Comment: @rm1512 now it will search for the string and set that as the first cell in the countifs.

Comment: @rm1512 your photo looks like Google Sheets.  The Edit above will not work in Google Sheets

Comment: Does the input in B1 also need to be a string or can it be an excel date formatted the same as the string dates?  I suspect it has to be a string but I am not sure hence the question

Comment: @ForwardEd it would need to match value in the search column.